# How to save edits to a R Shiny datatable cell but not save any filters from a sliderInput?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, reactive, dt

I'm trying to build an editable datatable in R Shiny that saves changes to the cells to the original file.

I also want users to be able to filter the dataset, but I do **not** want any filters to affect the original file. For instance, if you change the Sepal.Length of a cell to be 400, I want to see that saved to the original file; however, if you filter the file, I want to still see all the observations in the original file.

I have parts of it figured out, but I cannot get all the parts to come together. Here's a below example using the iris data.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

#Saving iris to your desktop, so you can confirm if file is being edited
data("iris")
write_csv(iris, "~/desktop/iris.test") #my file path; you may need to edit

dt_output = function(title, id) {
    fluidRow(column(
        12, h1(paste0('Table ', sub('.*?([0-9]+)$', '\\1', id), ': ', title)),
        hr(), DTOutput(id)
    ))
}
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
    renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}

shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
        title = 'Double-click to edit table cells',
        sliderInput("slide",
                    "Slider",
                    min = min(iris$Sepal.Length),
                    max = max(iris$Sepal.Length),
                    value = mean(iris$Sepal.Length)),
        
        dt_output('edit rows but disable certain columns (editable = list(target = "row", disable = list(columns = c(2, 4, 5))))', 'x10')
    ),
    
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        d1 = read_csv("~/desktop/iris.test") #my file path; you may need to edit for reproducibility
        d1$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d1))

        d2 = reactive({
            d1 %>%
                dplyr::filter(Sepal.Length > input$slide)
        })
        
        options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
        

        output$x10 = render_dt(d2(), list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(2, 4, 5))))
        

        # edit rows but disable columns 2, 4, 5
        observeEvent(input$x10_cell_edit, {
            d3 <<- editData(d2(), input$x10_cell_edit, 'x10')
            write_csv(d3, "~/desktop/iris.test") #my file path; you may need to edit for reproducibility
        })
        
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You may use `reactiveValues` to save your original dataset and change the values in it.
- Create a row number column to make it easier to change values on the correct row.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

write_csv(iris, "iris.test.csv") 

dt_output = function(title, id) {
  fluidRow(column(
    12, h1(paste0('Table ', sub('.*?([0-9]+)$', '\\1', id), ': ', title)),
    hr(), DTOutput(id)
  ))
}
render_dt = function(data, editable = 'cell', server = TRUE, ...) {
  renderDT(data, selection = 'none', server = server, editable = editable, ...)
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Double-click to edit table cells',
    sliderInput("slide",
                "Slider",
                min = min(iris$Sepal.Length),
                max = max(iris$Sepal.Length),
                value = mean(iris$Sepal.Length)),
    
    dt_output('edit rows but disable certain columns (editable = list(target = "row", disable = list(columns = c(2, 4, 5))))', 'x10')
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    d1 = read_csv("iris.test.csv") %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>% as.data.frame()
    d1$Date = Sys.time() + seq_len(nrow(d1))
    rv <- reactiveValues(data = d1)
    
    d2 = reactive({
      d1 %>%
        dplyr::filter(Sepal.Length > input$slide)
    })
    
    options(DT.options = list(pageLength = 5))
    
    
    output$x10 = render_dt(d2(), list(target = 'cell', disable = list(columns = c(2, 4, 5))))
    
    
    # edit rows but disable columns 2, 4, 5
    observeEvent(input$x10_cell_edit, {
      tmp <- d2()
      row <- tmp$row[input$x10_cell_edit$row]
      rv$data[row, input$x10_cell_edit$col] <- input$x10_cell_edit$value
      write_csv(rv$data, "iris.test.csv") 
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: I tried this but when I used the slider, it still didn't adjust (the number of shown observations never reduced).